# Traefik on a rpi kubernetes node return 404 page not found

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, kubernetes, traefik, hypriot

I try to made a first experience on kubernetes by practice.

kubernetes v1.9 has been setup on 5 raspberry pi mounted as cluster.

OS : hypriot v1.4

**host / static ip configured / raspberry hardware version :**

- master: 192.168.1.230 / rpi v3
- node01: 192.168.1.231 / rpi v3
- node02: 192.168.1.232 / rpi v3
- node03: 192.168.1.233 / rpi v2
- node04: 192.168.1.234 / rpi v2

For the pod network I choose Weave Net. Traefik has been installed in the **node01** as load balancer to access my service from outside.
I ssh the master and use these commands to install it (origin: https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-kubernetes-raspberry-pi-cluster/) :

$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hypriot/rpi-traefik/master/traefik-k8s-example.yaml

$ kubectl label node node01 nginx-controller=traefik

All system pods are running.
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
kube-system   etcd-master                                  1/1       Running   5          22h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master                        1/1       Running   40         13h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master               1/1       Running   10         13h
kube-system   kube-dns-7b6ff86f69-x58pj                    3/3       Running   9          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-5bqwh                             1/1       Running   2          15h
kube-system   kube-proxy-kngp9                             1/1       Running   2          16h
kube-system   kube-proxy-n85xl                             1/1       Running   5          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-ncg2k                             1/1       Running   2          15h
kube-system   kube-proxy-qbfcf                             1/1       Running   2          21h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master                        1/1       Running   5          22h
kube-system   traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc-7rhpf   1/1       Running   1          14h
kube-system   weave-net-6mvc6                              2/2       Running   31         15h
kube-system   weave-net-8hff9                              2/2       Running   31         15h
kube-system   weave-net-9kwgr                              2/2       Running   31         21h
kube-system   weave-net-llgrk                              2/2       Running   41         22h
kube-system   weave-net-s2h62                              2/2       Running   29         16h
```

The issue is when I try to connect to the node01 by using this url http://192.168.1.231/. I got a 404 page not found...

So I checked the log and figure out that they are a problem with the default account :

$ kubectl logs traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc-7rhpf

```
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E1226 07:29:15.195193       1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list endpoints at the cluster scope
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E1226 07:29:15.422807       1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list secrets at the cluster scope
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E1226 07:29:15.915317       1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list services at the cluster scope
ERROR: logging before flag.Parse: E1226 07:29:16.108385       1 reflector.go:199] github.com/containous/traefik/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list ingresses.extensions at the cluster scope
```

Is it really a problem with the account system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default used? What account should I use instead of?

Thanks for helping.

Additional informations:

$ docker -v
    Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22

$ kubectl describe pods traefik-ingress-controller -n kube-system

```
Name:         traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc-7rhpf
Namespace:    kube-system
Node:         node01/192.168.1.231
Start Time:   Mon, 25 Dec 2017 20:54:45 +0000
Labels:       k8s-app=traefik-ingress-controller
              pod-template-hash=587301077
Annotations:  scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations=[
  {
    "key": "dedicated",
    "operator": "Equal",
    "value": "master",
    "effect": "NoSchedule"
  }
]

Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.1.231
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc
Containers:
  traefik-ingress-controller:
    Container ID:  docker://9e28800da6937a48aa20b5ef6526846b321a516ad20ee24ea3d32876f6769531
    Image:         hypriot/rpi-traefik
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://hypriot/rpi-traefik@sha256:ecdfcd94571ec8c121c20a6ec616d68aeaad93150a0717260196f813e31737d9
    Ports:         80/TCP, 8888/TCP
    Args:
      --web
      --web.address=localhost:8888
      --kubernetes
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:24:33 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 20:54:50 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:17:09 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  30Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     20Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4wzhl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-4wzhl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4wzhl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  nginx-controller=traefik
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>

Name:         traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc-jszgz
Namespace:    kube-system
Node:         node01/
Start Time:   Mon, 25 Dec 2017 18:28:21 +0000
Labels:       k8s-app=traefik-ingress-controller
              pod-template-hash=587301077
Annotations:  scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerations=[
  {
    "key": "dedicated",
    "operator": "Equal",
    "value": "master",
    "effect": "NoSchedule"
  }
]

Status:         Failed
Reason:         MatchNodeSelector
Message:        Pod Predicate MatchNodeSelector failed
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/traefik-ingress-controller-9dc7454cc
Containers:
  traefik-ingress-controller:
    Image:  hypriot/rpi-traefik
    Ports:  80/TCP, 8888/TCP
    Args:
      --web
      --web.address=localhost:8888
      --kubernetes
    Limits:
      cpu:     200m
      memory:  30Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     20Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4wzhl (ro)
Volumes:
  default-token-4wzhl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4wzhl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  nginx-controller=traefik
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

$ kubectl describe pods weave-net-9kwgr -n kube-system

```
Name:           weave-net-llgrk
Namespace:      kube-system
Node:           master/192.168.1.230
Start Time:     Mon, 25 Dec 2017 13:33:40 +0000
Labels:         controller-revision-hash=2209123374
                name=weave-net
                pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.1.230
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/weave-net
Containers:
  weave:
    Container ID:  docker://7824b8b02f1a8f5a53d7f27f0c12b44f73a4b666a694b974142f974294bedd6c
    Image:         weaveworks/weave-kube:2.1.3
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://weaveworks/weave-kube@sha256:07a3d56b8592ea3e00ace6f2c3eb7e65f3cc4945188a9e2a884b8172e6a0007e
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      /home/weave/launch.sh
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:13:58 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:08:38 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:08:50 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  37
    Requests:
      cpu:     10m
    Liveness:  http-get http://127.0.0.1:6784/status delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      HOSTNAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /host/etc from cni-conf (rw)
      /host/home from cni-bin2 (rw)
      /host/opt from cni-bin (rw)
      /host/var/lib/dbus from dbus (rw)
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (rw)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from weave-net-token-mx5jk (ro)
      /weavedb from weavedb (rw)
  weave-npc:
    Container ID:   docker://b199904c10ed34501748c25e13862113aeb32c7779b0797d72c95f9e9d868331
    Image:          weaveworks/weave-npc:2.1.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://weaveworks/weave-npc@sha256:f35eb8166d7dae3fa7bb4d9892ab6dc8ea5c969f73791be590a0a213767c0f07
    Port:           <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:24:32 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 20:54:30 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:17:09 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  4
    Requests:
      cpu:  10m
    Environment:
      HOSTNAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from weave-net-token-mx5jk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  weavedb:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/weave
    HostPathType:
  cni-bin:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt
    HostPathType:
  cni-bin2:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home
    HostPathType:
  cni-conf:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc
    HostPathType:
  dbus:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/dbus
    HostPathType:
  lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  xtables-lock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/xtables.lock
    HostPathType:
  weave-net-token-mx5jk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  weave-net-token-mx5jk
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
Events:          <none>
root@master:/home/pirate# kubectl describe pods weave-net-9kwgr -n kube-system
Name:           weave-net-9kwgr
Namespace:      kube-system
Node:           node01/192.168.1.231
Start Time:     Mon, 25 Dec 2017 14:50:37 +0000
Labels:         controller-revision-hash=2209123374
                name=weave-net
                pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             192.168.1.231
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/weave-net
Containers:
  weave:
    Container ID:  docker://92e31f645b4dcd41e4d8189a6f67fa70a395971e071d635dc4c4208b8d1daf63
    Image:         weaveworks/weave-kube:2.1.3
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://weaveworks/weave-kube@sha256:07a3d56b8592ea3e00ace6f2c3eb7e65f3cc4945188a9e2a884b8172e6a0007e
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      /home/weave/launch.sh
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:13:39 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:08:17 +0000
      Finished:     Tue, 26 Dec 2017 00:08:28 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  29
    Requests:
      cpu:     10m
    Liveness:  http-get http://127.0.0.1:6784/status delay=30s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      HOSTNAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /host/etc from cni-conf (rw)
      /host/home from cni-bin2 (rw)
      /host/opt from cni-bin (rw)
      /host/var/lib/dbus from dbus (rw)
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (rw)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from weave-net-token-mx5jk (ro)
      /weavedb from weavedb (rw)
  weave-npc:
    Container ID:   docker://ddd86bef74d3fd40134c8609551cc07658aa62a2ede7ce51aec394001049e96d
    Image:          weaveworks/weave-npc:2.1.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://weaveworks/weave-npc@sha256:f35eb8166d7dae3fa7bb4d9892ab6dc8ea5c969f73791be590a0a213767c0f07
    Port:           <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:24:32 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Mon, 25 Dec 2017 20:54:30 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 25 Dec 2017 22:17:09 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  2
    Requests:
      cpu:  10m
    Environment:
      HOSTNAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from weave-net-token-mx5jk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  weavedb:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/weave
    HostPathType:
  cni-bin:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt
    HostPathType:
  cni-bin2:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home
    HostPathType:
  cni-conf:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc
    HostPathType:
  dbus:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/dbus
    HostPathType:
  lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  xtables-lock:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /run/xtables.lock
    HostPathType:
  weave-net-token-mx5jk:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  weave-net-token-mx5jk
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     :NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute
Events:          <none>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Traefik service account is missing proper RBAC privileges. By default, no application may access any Kubernetes API.

You have to make sure that the necessary rights are granted. Please check [our Kubernetes guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#role-based-access-control-configuration-kubernetes-16-only) for details.

Comment: This makes it kind of funny that the link also shows 404 ><